# How to stack a kernel above each point on a regular grid with Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density

The idea is to stack a kernel above each point scattered along 1D. Specifically, the peak of the kernel is align/ centered to x-axis point each of the point. This is akin to  [Kernel Density Estimation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_kde_1d.html) except only half of the kernel is stacked at each of the point as shown at the picture below.

[image]

Ultimately, the summation of each of density will be calculated and will yield a single curve (i.e., gray line) as shown below.

As a starting point, I had dig around the Kernel Density Estimation of [scikit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/neighbors/_kde.py#L27) learn module for an idea. However, I fail to find any line on how/where the stack they kernel on top each of point.

Really appreciate if someone can provide a good reading material for me to achieve this objective.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this do what you want? Sorry the graphs are not half as pretty as yours but did not think that was the point

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

# define a half-kernel function. We normalize to have integral(half_kernel) = 1 if required
def half_kernel(x, center, width = 1, normalize = True):
    kernel = (x>=center)*norm.pdf(x, center, width)
    if normalize:
        kernel *= 2
    return kernel

# this are the points where we center our kernels -- random for testing
centers = np.random.normal(0.0,2.0,7)

# Grid on which we look at the results
x = np.linspace(-3.0,3.0,101)

# get the results here, each column is one of the kernels 
discr_kernels = np.zeros((len(x),len(centers)))
for n in range(len(centers)):
    discr_kernels[:,n] = half_kernel(x, centers[n])
y = discr_kernels.sum(axis= 1)

plt.plot(x,discr_kernels,'--')
plt.plot(x,y, '.-', label = 'total')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
```

[image: result]

Comment: Awesome @piterbag. At first glance this looks like something that I desire. But let me inspect in depth the summation of all density (gray line) first.