# How to stack a kernel above each point with Seaborn kdeplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The objective is  to stack a kernel above each point scattered along 1D. Based on [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64889482/6446053), this can be achieved as below.

```
# define a half-kernel function. We normalize to have integral(half_kernel) = 1 if required
def half_kernel(x, center, width = 1, normalize = True):
    kernel = norm.pdf ( x, center, width )
    if normalize:
        kernel *= 2
    return kernel

# this are the points where we center our kernels -- random for testing
centers = np.array([5,5,5,1,2,1,1,8])
# Grid on which we look at the results
x = np.linspace(0,10,101)

# get the results here, each column is one of the kernels
discr_kernels = np.zeros((len(x),len(centers)))
for n in range(len(centers)):
    discr_kernels[:,n] = half_kernel(x, centers[n])
y = discr_kernels.sum(axis= 1)

plt.plot(x,discr_kernels,'--')
plt.plot(x,y, '.-', label = 'total')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```

and produce

[image]

Since seaborn offer greater flexibility in customization, I would instead to replicate this using seaborn.

```
df =DataFrame ([5,5,5,1,2,1,1,8],columns=['seq_no'])
sns.kdeplot(data=df, x="seq_no")
plt.show()
```

However, the result is not the same

[image]

Really appreciate if someone can share any insight what setting needed to be change on the seaborn, to get similar output as provided using the first approach.

Comment: You can adjust the bandwidth used for the [kde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation):  `sns.kdeplot(data=df, x="seq_no", bw_adjust=0.5)` to get a similar plot.

Comment: Note that the default bandwidth usually is calculated via Scott's rule. See [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seaborn kdeplot` [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) says that,

> The bandwidth, or standard deviation of the smoothing kernel, is an
> important parameter. Misspecification of the bandwidth can produce a
> distorted representation of the data. Much like the choice of bin
> width in a histogram, an over-smoothed curve can erase true features
> of a distribution, while an under-smoothed curve can create false
> features out of random variability. The rule-of-thumb that sets the
> default bandwidth works best when the true distribution is smooth,
> unimodal, and roughly bell-shaped. It is always a good idea to check
> the default behavior by using `bw_adjust` to increase or decrease the
> amount of smoothing.

This would do a trick.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([5,5,5,1,2,1,1,8],columns=['seq_no'])
sns.kdeplot(data=df, x="seq_no", bw_adjust=0.6);plt.xlim(0,10);plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]